# Forms for a NYS LLC to elect LLC/non-S Corp taxation

Tags: united-states, tax-law, new-york-state, limited-liability-company, corporate-tax-laws

NY state (USA) here. If a 1-man NYS LLC wishes to elect S-corporation taxation status, they must file a [Form 2553](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-form-2553) with the IRS, and a [Form CT-6](https://www.tax.ny.gov/pdf/current_forms/ct/ct6_fill_in.pdf) with the NYS Department of Taxation and Finance.

At a later time, they may wish to undo these tax elections and *revert* back to an LLC that elects "normal" LLC taxation status.

What forms must it fill out, both federal and state, to make this change?

Comment: It is important to note that the premise in your first paragraph is incomplete. One must complete IRS Form 8832 to elect to be taxed as a corporation rather than as a disregarded entity before a firm is eligible to file Form 2553 and Form CT-6. https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f8832.pdf The answer is largely embedded in that observation but I don't have time to spell it out at the moment.

Comment: Hmmm @ohwilleke, from that link: "_An eligible entity is classified for federal tax purposes under the default rules described below unless it files Form 8832 or Form 2553_". I interpret that as: "default rules apply unless you file _either_ Form 8832 **or** Form 2553." So, at least according to that blurb, does not require you to first file 8832 and then only 2553 once eligibility is unlocked...no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: I misunderstood the situation and will amend but leave original answer
below with comment.

**For an LLC to stop being treated as S Corp, file [Form CT-6.1](https://www.tax.ny.gov/pdf/current_forms/ct/ct6_1.pdf) with NYS DTF.**

**For the IRS, there is no form([IRS source](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/revoking-a-subchapter-s-election)). Instead you have to file a statement to the service center where you file tax returns.
The statement should state:**

- The corporation revokes the election made under Section 1362(a)
- Name of the shareholder(s),
- Address of the shareholder(s),
- Taxpayer identification number of the shareholder(s),
- The number of shares of stock owned by the shareholder(s),
- The date (or dates) on which the stock was acquired
- The date on which the shareholder's taxable year ends
- The name of the S corporation
- The S corporation's EIN
- The election to which the shareholder(s) revokes
- The statement must be signed by the shareholder(s) under penalties of perjury
- Signature and consent of shareholder(s) who collectively own more than 50% of the number of issued and outstanding stock of the corporation, whether voting or non-voting)
- Indication of the effective date of the revocation (or prospective date)
- Signature of person authorized to sign return

*My first answer below applied to S Corps wanting to become LLC, which is not what was asked:*

*New York does not allow a corporation to change into an LLC. Instead you must create a new LLC by filing [Articles of Organization](https://dos.ny.gov/system/files/documents/2022/06/1336-f.pdf) and then have the S Corp assumed by the new LLC by filing a [Certificate of Merger](https://dos.ny.gov/system/files/documents/2019/01/1372-f.pdf). Both filings are with the NY Department of State. If this is your livelihood, please talk to a lawyer.*

Comment: This applies to an LLC that elected S-corp taxation?

Comment: @hotmeatballsoup I fixed the answer

Comment: Amazing answer thanks @IKnowNothing (+1) -- I'll leave this open for another day or 2 in case anything else crops up but I really appreciate this

Answer (score 1):

Single-member NY state LLCs do not have to file taxes regardless of what tax status they have previously elected. This is known as the [S Corp loop hole](https://www.incnow.com/tax-tips/).

At the Federal level, filing a [Form 1120](https://www.irs.gov/businesses/small-businesses-self-employed/llc-filing-as-a-corporation-or-partnership#:%7E:text=If%20the%20LLC%20is%20a%20corporation%2C%20normal%20corporate%20tax%20rules,U.S.%20Corporation%20Income%20Tax%20Return.) is all you need.

Comment: The question is how to be taxed going forward as a sole proprietorship if one has previously been taxed as an S-corporation. This answer addresses what forms to complete while you are an S-corporation which is non-responsive.

Comment: Actually I _am_ asking what forms need to be filed @ohwilleke. It's literally the last sentence of my question... **and** the title of the question.